# Write a function that can work as `labels(x) <- some_value`

Tags: r, select, methods

I want to write a function, `labels`,  that works as follows:

```
x <- 1:6
labels(x)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

labels(x) <- 2:7
labels(x)
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7

labels(x)[1:2] <- 9:10
labels(x)
# [1] 9 10 4 5 6 7
```

How can I do so?

Comment: This is better asked now, before one could have answered with labels <- function(x) names(x).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you seem to want is to understand *replacement* functions. If we look at `names`, we also note that there is a `names<-` function as well, with the following definition:

```
> `names<-`
function (x, value)  .Primitive("names<-")
```

Which isn't very informative about what it actually does, but shows that you can write any function of the form `foo<-` that replaces some components of the object the function is applied to.

```
x <- 1:6
X <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)

Labels <- function(obj, ...) {
    UseMethod("Labels")
}

Labels.numeric <- function(obj, ...) {
    names(obj)
}

Labels.matrix <- function(obj, which = c("colnames","rownames"), ...) {
    if(missing(which))
        which <- "colnames"
    which <- match.arg(which)
    if(which == "colnames") {
        out <- colnames(obj)
    } else {
        out <- rownames(obj)
    }
    out
}

`Labels<-` <- function(obj, ..., value) {
    UseMethod("Labels<-")
}

`Labels<-.numeric` <- function(obj, ..., value) {
    names(obj) <- value
    obj
}
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
> x <- 1:6
> Labels(x)
NULL
> Labels(x) <- LETTERS[1:6]
> x
A B C D E F 
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

A matrix method, might be:

```
`Labels<-.matrix` <- function(obj, which = c("colnames","rownames"), ..., value) {
    if(missing(which))
            which <- "colnames"
        which <- match.arg(which)
        if(which == "colnames") {
            colnames(obj) <- value
        } else {
            rownames(obj) <- value
        }
        obj
}
```

Which is used as:

```
> Labels(X)
NULL
> Labels(X) <- letters[1:3]
> X
     a b c
[1,] 1 4 7
[2,] 2 5 8
[3,] 3 6 9
> Labels(X, which = "rownames") <- LETTERS[24:26]
> X
  a b c
X 1 4 7
Y 2 5 8
Z 3 6 9
```

The trick is to remember that replacement functions are called with a `value` argument that takes the values from the right hand side of `<-`, so your function definition needs to have a `value` argument, and use this argument to set/change the labels.

Of course, all this can be done using `names`, `colnames` etc, but if you want to understand how this works then hopefully the above is of use?

Comment: Gavin, your answer was very well structured - thank you for the detailed explanation.  BTW, this will now enable me to define what I was really after ("labels<-.dendrogram").  Thanks again, Tal

Comment: Hi Gavin,
I wanted to let you know that I finally got around to wrapping a function for dendrogram labels, based on your help here, into a new package I'm now putting together.  Thanks again :)  Tal   (https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend/blob/master/R/labels.r)

Answer (score 2):

If you replace "labels" with "names" it will work right now.

```
x <- 1:6
names(x)
names(x) <- 2:7
# and now that x "names" will be 2:7
names(x)[1:2] <- 9:10 # being able to do this is really cool
x
9 10 4 5 6 7
1  2 3 4 5 6
```

?names is general to many R objects: vectors, lists, data.frames, and is supported for each by [ and [[, and can be easily applied to new classes and methods.

Comment: Thanks for replying mdsumner.  But as I wrote, I wish to understand how the relevant internal code might be written in R.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see that in the question as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

here is an example:

```
`f` <- function(x) {
  x$a   
}

`f<-` <- function(x, value){
  x$a <- value
  x
}
```

then,

```
> d <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=3:1)
> f(d) <- 2
> print(d)
  a b
1 2 3
2 2 2
3 2 1
> 
> f(d)[3] <- 3
> print(d)
  a b
1 2 3
2 2 2
3 3 1
```

what you have to do is to define function `f` and `f<-`.

and although I'm not sure what you expect to "label" function, here is the most simple example of replacement:

```
`labels` <- function(x) x
`labels<-` <- function(x, value) x <- value
```

then,

```
> x <- 1:6
> labels(x)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> labels(x) <- 2:7
> x
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7
> labels(x)[1:2] <- 9:10
> x
[1]  9 10  4  5  6  7
```

Comment: Perfect kohske - exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand your question well, but I think you need a factor here, which has values and labels (levels). E.g.:

```
> x <- as.factor(1:7)
> x
     [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
     Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> levels(x)
     [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7"
> levels(x)[1:2] <- 9:10
> x
     [1] 9  10 3  4  5  6  7 
     Levels: 9 10 3 4 5 6 7
> as.numeric(x)
    [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```